# Js unterminated string constant for .append dynamic table

Tags: javascript

I am creating a table dynamically using data in an array:

```
var toAppend = $("#tablediv");
toAppend.append("<table id=\"grid\"><tr><th>(labels)</th>");
for (var f = 0; f < seriescount; f++)
{
    toAppend.append("<th>" + series[f] + "</th>");
}
toAppend.append("</tr></table>");
```

The final line returns an 'unterminated string constant' error. This goes away by removing the line or changing its contents - this is something to do with it being a closing tag.

This code is in  tags within C# Razor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A document fragment is always closed. You can't append half elements.

So when you do

```
toAppend.append("<table id=\"grid\"><tr><th>(labels)</th>");
```

what you really do is

```
toAppend.append("<table id=\"grid\"><tr><th>(labels)</th></tr></table>");
```

A simple solution here is to build an HTML string and do only one `append` with the complete string :

```
var h = "<table id=grid><tr><th>(labels)</th>";
for (var f = 0; f < seriescount; f++) {
    h += "<th>" + series[f] + "</th>";
}
h += "</tr></table>";
$("#tablediv").append(h);
```